# Setting foreground color for all TextBlocks in a Grid in one place in XAML (Silverlight, WP)

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone, grid-layout, foreground

Let's say we have a construction like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

How can I set the foreground color for all textblocks in the grid as one setting?
Something similar to

```
<Grid Color="Red">
     ...
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a resources on the grid that sets all textBlock foreground's to red.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" >Good show</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >Now the Foreground is red</TextBlock>

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But in my real-world app, another style is applied to some TextBlocks, and this color setting isn't used for them.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternate to @Onosa's answer -- `Foreground` is one of those dependency properties that is inherited down the visual tree.  So you could also wrap your Grid in any subclass of [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.foreground(v=vs.110).aspx), for example `ContentControl`:

```
<ContentControl Foreground="Red">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Yes, it's a better solution than Onosa's answer - see my comment why.

Comment: I did not know that. Thank you for sharing. @TecMan, it wouldn't bother me if you marked this as the answer instead of mine.

Comment: @Onosa, it was my fault as I simplified my real XAML code to the max to ask a neat question. Your answer is 100% correct if we look at my question.